# submit button con confirmacion

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

tengo un boton de enviar

```
{!! Form::submit('Registrar',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'] ) !!}
```

funciona bien, pero quisiera ver si hay alguna opcion rapida de pregunta de confirmacion. ejemplo

```
onclick="return confirm('¿Estas Seguro?')"
```

he intentado leer la documentacion de laravel y de laravel collective. pero no logro solucionarlo. alguien sabe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no existe algo así en Laravel o en el FormBuilder de LaravelCollective.

---

Lo más sencillo tal vez podría ser agregar el código que muestras al Form, con el evento `onsubmit`:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'onsubmit' => 'return confirm("¿Estas Seguro?")']) !!}
```

Comment: si muchas gracias, me solucionastes un problema una vez mas!!! jejeje. nunca dejes este grupo. :P